# Exception: Class Not Found in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, namespaces

I get the error:

Exception - *Class 'sites\output\tab_gamify' not found* when load an edit page.

I have a file named sites/classes/output/edit.php with something like:

```
<?php

namespace sites\output;

class edit extends tabs {

      public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
             parent::__construct($attributes);

             ...
             ...
             $this->add_tab(new tab_gamify($attributes));
      }

}
```

And a file named sites/classes/output/tab_gamify.php with something like:

```
<?php

namespace sites\output;

class tab_gamify extends tab {
      ...
      ...
}
```

I get the previous error message and and i not able to locate my error. Any suggestion or clue will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

I've revised namespaces, also reloaded and restarted docker container.

Comment: This both files is inside same folder ?

Comment: yes, both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Have you PHP autoloader ?

Comment: Yes, I have PHP autoloader. Indeed, I've made a similar call in others parts of my code...